# How to get Preview to ALWAYS open image in a new window

Tags: preview

I have my Preview preferences set to open images in a new window. Before upgrading to Big Sur this worked unconditionally.  Since switching to Big Sur this works for the first 15 windows, but after that, it starts opening them in an existing window.  I can right click and open them in a new window, but it is really inconvenient.  Can I tweak a setting somewhere, possibly from the command line, to be have Preview continue to open images in new windows?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to switch programs.  Xee^3 does the job.